# How do I find a function with specific coordinates?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Suppose I have a set of several $(x,y)$ coordinates, how would I find some function $f(x)=y$ which satisfies these coordinates? Is there a website I can use? Does there always exist a function which satisfies any set of points?

Comment: Are you talking about a set of $(x,y)$ coordinates?

Comment: yes x , y coords

Comment: Given $n$ points you can find a unique $n-1$ degree polynomial that goes through them.  Look up Lagrange interpolation.

Answer (score 1):

If you have several points $(x,y)$ , then you can make a set $S$ as a collection of them. Now, if there exists no point $y,z$ and $y\neq z$ such that both $(x,y),(x,z)$ belongs to the set $S$, then according to definition of function, this set $S$ is a function and it has the property you want. Although it may not be possible to write this function with the help of $+,-,\times,\sin,\cos,\ln$ and variables. However, if you have a collection of points like this:
$$S=\{(1,2),(1,3)\} $$

Then there exists no function with the property you want. That is : for any given collection of points there does not always exist a function with the property you mentioned.